# MSVCR100D.dll error at runtime

Tags: c++

Ok , so i created a program using VC++ 2010. it ran just fine.

Got to work and could only install vc++ 8 due to having a crappy computer that is still stuck on xp sp2...

Everything will link up and build with no errors, But when the program starts to run i get "This application has failed to start because MSVCR100D.dll was not found"

I tried changing the runtime libary from MDd to MTd but still no luck...any idea?

Comment: Only ever copy the Release build of your program.  The debug version of the CRT, the "D" part of the name, is only available on a machine that has VS installed.  And of course you never want your user to run a slow version of your program either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That DLL comes with Visual Studio 2010. If you want to use your program, you'll somehow have to get your hands on it. If possible at your work, you can [download](http://www.dll-files.com/dllindex/dll-files.shtml?msvcr100d) it. Another (probably better) option would be to take it with you from home on a USB drive.

Edit: You can also try re-creating the project, and then copying the source code over into the new project. Your newly created project (in Visual Studio 2008) should not be depending on that erroneous DLL.

Edit 2: As Hans Passant added in a comment, this DLL is needed by `Debug` compilations of your program. So if you simply compile as `Release`, you can safely ignore the first part of my post. (I hope I'm not breaking gentleman rules by adding this to my post.)

Comment: thanks download worked! While other answers would have worked too you where first thanks!

Comment: Either way, do try to get a Release version of the program, so that you won't even need that DLL anymore.

Answer (score 1):

MSVCR100D.dll is for debug mode, and is installed with visual studio 2010, since 2008 has MSVCR80D. You can just google that and download it, and put it in the same direcrory, or just complie in release mode.

here is a download link. You need the small download zip file button, not the big ones.
http://www.dll-files.com/dllindex/dll-files.shtml?msvcr100d

Comment: Please don't make duplicate answers; this was already posted 15 minutes ago.

Answer (score 0):

As I know, MSVCR100D is debug version of runtime library used by VC2010。So, if your point either is:

(1) you do not have that dll which you really need, you can download at http://www.dll-files.com/dllindex/dll-files.shtml?msvcr100d or

(2) you want to run that program without requirement of MSVCR100/D.dll, you may need to recreate a project in VC8, then substitute with your source files (not solution file or other files managed by Vistual Studio).

FYI: If my memory were not going wrong, I remember that a project created by higher version of VS cannot be opened directly by lower version one. So, how did you build them?